# Laravel 5.1 belongsTo Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to echo out the name of the user in my article and I'm getting the `ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object`. Here is my code:

Model (I have a User model too):

```
1. News

    class News extends Model
    {
      public function postedBy()
      {
         return $this->belongsTo('User');
      }
      protected $table = 'tcity_news';
      protected $fillable = ['newsContent', 'newsTitle', 'postedBy'];
    }

2. User

    class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                AuthorizableContract,
                                CanResetPasswordContract
    {
        use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

        protected $table = 'users';

        protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

        protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    }
```

Controller:

```
public function showArticle($slug)
    {
        $article = News::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
        return view('article', compact('article'));
    }
```

Blade:

```
{{ $article->postedBy->name }}
```

When I try to remove name in the blade `{{ $article->postedBy }}` it echoes out the id, but when I try to add the `->name` there it says `Trying to get property of non-object` but I have a field `name` in my table and `User` model. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:** When I try what user dschu said which is `{{ dd( $article->postedBy) }}` , I get the id of the user.

Comment: Could you please {{ dd( $article->postedBy) }} and post your result? I just want to make sure, that this is actual the user model you get.

Comment: @dschu Hi thanks, I got the id of the user

Comment: So a string instead of the model?? Try dd( $article->postetBy->get() ) then.

Comment: @dschu I get Call to a member function get() on a non-object because it's in a blade

Comment: Could you post your Users model? And try changing your News model like this: $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id'); 'user_id' should be the field in your Users table, where the ID is stored. (Maybe just id?)

Comment: @dschu Hello, I added my User model. User and News have same primary key named id

Comment: Where is the user_id stored inside the News model? Try adding this key to belongsTo as second parameter.

Comment: @dschu the user_id is stored in the column postedBy of the News model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89070/discussion-between-dschu-and-fewflyby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you seem to have the same name (postedBy) for your relationship and the field in you database.

You should have a field called user_id instead of postedBy (or userId to be consistent).

Comment: You can pass 'user_id' as a second parameter to the belongsTo method like this:  $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id'); In this case, he should be fine with postedBy.

Comment: @dschu Well, I don't really think it's better to read because yes you'll know what it refers but it gives you no information on what you are storing.
Also, I don't know how Laravel will handle to have an attribute and a relationship with the same name, when he calls $news->postedBy, does it refers the field in the DB or the relationship? Not sure about the answer.

Comment: You are right – On a second thought, I came to the same conclusion, which is the reason why I edited my answer. :)

Comment: HI, I will try this when I get back to the office. Thank you